# array_pop() expects parameter 1 to be array in Wordpress related posts by taxonomy code

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, syntax-error

> Warning: array_pop() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in ... on line 34

I get the following error when using the following function. The output of the function works as expected except the error shows up before the output.

```
<?php 
global $post;

//Get the terms for the current post
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID , 'character', 'string');
echo $terms[1];
$potentials = array();
$c = 0;
$totalFound = 0;

//Gather your posts for each term
foreach($terms as $term){
   $q = array(
    'character' => $term->slug, //term to retrieve from custom taxonomy
    'numberposts' => 3,  //limit to 4 posts
    'post_type' => 'videos', //get only posts
    'exclude' => $post->ID //exclude current post
   );
   $posts = get_posts($q);
   $totalFound+= count($posts);
   $potentials[$c++] = array_reverse($posts);
}

$count = 0;  //The number of good posts we've found
$index = 0;  //Number of posts we've tried
$max = $totalFound > 3 ? 3 : $totalFound;  //The max we can find
$posts = array();

//Now pick one post from each term until we reach our quota,
//or have checked them all
while($count < $max){

  //Pop off a post to use
  $rpost = array_pop($potentials[$index++]);

  //if we got a post (if there was one left)
  if($rpost){
    //don't take duplicates
    if(!isset($posts[$rpost->ID])){
      $posts[$rpost->ID] = $rpost;
      $count++;
    }
  }
  $index = ($index % 3); //rotate through the 4 term arrays
}
foreach($posts as $post){
    setup_postdata($post);
    $exclusive = get('aoexclusive_yes');
    if(!$exclusive) {$exclusive = null;} else {$exclusive = 'exclusive';}
    $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(  $post->ID ), "video-thumb" );
?>
                    <div class="thumb-post<?php echo ' '.$exclusive; ?>">
<?php if($image) { ?>

                        <a class="featured-image" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><img src="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>" /></a>
<?php } else { ?>

                        <a class="featured-image" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/assets/images/default.jpg" /></a>
<?php } ?>
                        <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
<?php ao_post_meta(); ?>    

                    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Does anyone have any experience with this error or see what might be causing it?

Code originally came from http://wordpress.org/support/topic/custom-taxonomy-related-posts-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're using array_pop on an index of the potentials array.
array_pop is designed to pop the last element off the end of an array.

Comment: Thanks Francis-- so what's the solution?

Comment: I'm not sure; I would have posted if I knew :) What are you trying to do with it? Are you trying to grab a single element of the array?

Comment: Also, what does the potentials array look like?

Answer (score 1):

`array_pop()` accepts an array as argument and it remove the last value from the array (returning it). If you want to get the value of that array element, you should do something like

```
$rpost = $potentials[$index++];
```

If you also need to remove it from the array, then you need something like this:

```
$rpost = $potentials[$index];
unset($potentials[$index]);
$index++;
```

Comment: Thanks, Entropy-- logically that seems like it should work perfectly, but I think the code I'm using is quite imperfect and throws the page into an infinite loop with that code. I ended up going with another plugin, found here http://pippinsplugins.com/write-a-better-related-posts-plugin-for-custom-taxonomies/ ... works perfectly

Comment: I think it happens because `$count` doesn't always get incremented correctly, so at some point it generates a loop.